# How to run innodb_force_recovery on MySQL on Windows

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to start MySQL in force recovery mode.  I've seen the documentation on innodb_force_recovery [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html): but it suggests adding a line to my "option file".

I don't know what the option file is, nor where it is in Windows.  I'm basically trying to follow this article [here](http://www.nerdydork.com/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows.html) but without using `XAMPP` and am stuck on the part about starting MySQL in recovery mode.

Can anyone tell me how to start MySQL with 'innodb_force_recovery = 6' on Windows 7?

Many thanks for any pointers folks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it.  I was able to add it as a rule in this file:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini
```

which I had to edit with admin privileges in Notepad.